# Leray projection on Besov spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm reading a book whose author claims it's very clear that $\mathbb P\nabla\cdot$ maps the Besov space $(B_{\infty,\infty}^{-N})^{d\times d}$ to $(B_{\infty,\infty}^{-N-1})^d$ where $\mathbb P$ is the Leray projection. Writing out $\|\mathbb P\nabla\cdot(u_{ij})\|_{(B_{\infty,\infty}^{-N-1})^d}$ using the Littlewood-Paley version of the norm, I could not arrive at the claim.

Am I missing something? Maybe an equivalent norm makes it easy? Or maybe the author just thinks it's intuitive, since you clearly lose one derivative by taking this operator.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can prove this using a combination of the Bernstein inequalities from Littlewood-Paley theory, the boundedness properties of the Riesz transforms, and a formula for the Leray projector in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Bernstein tells us that for $1\le p \le \infty$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^d$
$$
\Vert \partial^\alpha S_j u\Vert_p \lesssim \Vert S_j u \Vert_p 2^{|\alpha| j}
$$
for all $j$.

On the other hand if $R_i$ is the $i^{th}$ Riesz transform, i.e. the operator whose Fourier symbol is $\xi_i /|\xi|$, then $R_i$ is a bounded operator from $L^p$ to $L^p$ for $1 < p \le \infty$, and is a weak-type operator from $L^1$ to $L^{1,\infty}$.

One can show that the Leray projector takes the form $\mathbb{P} = I - R \otimes R$, i.e.
$$
(\mathbb{P} u)_i = u_i - \sum_{k=1}^d R_i R_k u_k.
$$
From this it's clear that we have the bound
$$
\Vert \mathbb{P} u\Vert_p \lesssim \Vert u \Vert_p \text{ for all } 1 < p \le \infty.
$$
Note also that $S_j$ commutes with $\nabla \cdot$ and $\mathbb{P}$.  Now we synthesize these:
$$
\Vert \mathbb{P} \nabla \cdot X \Vert_{B^{s-1}_{\infty,\infty}} =\sup_{j} 2^{j(s-1)} \Vert S_j \mathbb{P} \nabla \cdot  X\Vert_{\infty}  =\sup_{j} 2^{j(s-1)} \Vert  \mathbb{P} \nabla \cdot S_j X\Vert_{\infty} \\
\lesssim \sup_{j} 2^{j(s-1)} \Vert  \nabla \cdot S_j X\Vert_{\infty} 
\lesssim \sup_{j} 2^{js} \Vert   S_j X\Vert_{\infty} = \Vert  X \Vert_{B^{s}_{\infty,\infty}}.
$$

Hence $\mathbb{P} \nabla \cdot$ has the mapping properties you want for any $s$, not just for $s=-N$.

EDIT: I just realized that I messed up the range of $p$ for $R_i$.  In fact it's only bounded for $1 < p < \infty$.  I guess a different argument is needed for the boundedness of $\mathbb{P}$...  I'll think some more.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt. I think a strategy for getting past the $p=\infty$ issue could be to observe that the boundedness of $\mathbb P$ is only an issue at low frequencies, but the dyadic blocks cut out the low frequencies.